# Give an object which calls a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new in jQuery and i'm trying to give an object which triggers a function and gets its parent's ID. I have HTML:

```
<tr id="9"><td>First</td><td class="edit"></td><td class="delete" onclick="DeleteMaster(this)"></td></tr>
```

And jQuery function:

```
    function DeleteMaster(f){
    var master = f.parent().attr('id');
    alert (master);
}
```

But i'm getting an error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'parent'**

What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing in the DOM element, you need to convert this to a jQuery object:

```
function DeleteMaster(f){
    var master = $(f).parent().attr('id');
    alert (master);
}
```

**BUT**

You shouldn't declare `onclick` handlers like that. It's bad practice and can lead to hassle if you want to change it in the future. The standard jQuery way of doing things is:

```
// Wait for DOM to become ready
$(function() {
    // This replaces your "onclick" and "DeleteMaster" function
    $(".delete").on("click", function() {
        // Now you can access that <td> by calling $(this)
        var master = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    });
});
```

That way, you don't have to add code into your HTML markup.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `f` is not jquery object. You should use `$(f)` .Try this:

```
 function DeleteMaster(f){
  var master = $(f).parent().attr('id');
  alert (master);
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bMmpK/)**